# Fazer update no banco de dados via input utilizando ajax/php

Tags: php, ajax, input

Preciso realizar um update em uma tabela no banco de dados, lendo os dados digitados no input, ao clicar no botão. Isso é o que tenho até agora:

HTML:

```
<td>ADSL</td>

<td class="superdanger"> <input type="number"  id="vmadsl" placeholder="<?php echo "Valor atual: (Acima de ".$placeholder[0]."%)"; ?>"></input> </td>           

<td class="superwarning"> <input type="number"  id="aadsl" placeholder="<?php echo "Valor atual: (Acima de ".$placeholder[1]."%)"; ?>"></input> </td>

<td class="success"> <input type="number"  id="vdadsl" placeholder="<?php echo "Valor atual: (Acima de ".$placeholder[2]."%)"; ?>"></input> </td>


                <td> <button type="submit" id="teste"/</button> </td>
```

SCRIPT AJAX:

```
<script>
$(function(){
        $('#teste').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
            type      : 'post',

            url       : 'capacidade/relatorios/ricardo/matriz_capacidadericardo/attbutttonadsl.php',

            data      :  {vermelho: $('#vmadsl').val(), amarelo: $('#aadsl').val()},

            success: function (response) {
            alert('Alterado com sucesso');
            },
            error: function () {
            alert('Erro');
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    include 'capacidade/background_bd_conexao.php';

    $vermelhoadsl = $_POST["vermelho"];
    $amareloadsl = $_POST["amarelo"];

    mysql_query(" UPDATE valor FROM matriz_coloracao WHERE nome = 'Vermelho ADSL' SET valor = '".$vermelhoadsl."' ");
    mysql_query(" UPDATE valor FROM matriz_coloracao WHERE nome = 'Amarelo ADSL' SET valor = '".$amarelogadsl."' ");
?>
```

Comment: Não que tenha alguma a haver com o problema mas tem um erro no HTML: deve ser `<button type="submit" id="teste">BLABLAH</button>`

Comment: Qual erro você está tendo?

Comment: pode ser o envio do formulário, tente cancelar o evento ao clicar no botão  #teste

Comment: Ele não está alterando nada no banco, o erro me parece ser que ele não pega os valores de "vermelho" e "amarelo". Obrigado @Miguel

Comment: O alerto "Alterado com sucesso" chega a ser printado.

Answer (score -1):

Altere a maneira que você está enviando os dados na requisição ajax.

Segue exemplo abaixo.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#teste').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
        'type' : 'POST',

        'url'       : 'capacidade/relatorios/ricardo/matriz_capacidadericardo/attbutttonadsl.php',

        'data'      :  'vermelho=' + $('#vmadsl').val() + '&amarelo=' + $('#aadsl').val(),

        'success' : function (response) {
            alert('Alterado com sucesso');
        },
        error: function () {
        alert('Erro');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Insira seus inputs em um formdata para enviar no campo "data" do ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#teste').click(function(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.appen('vermelho',$('#vmadsl').val());
        fd.appen('amarelo',$('#aadsl').val());
        $.ajax({
        'type' : 'POST',

        'url'       : 'capacidade/relatorios/ricardo/matriz_capacidadericardo/attbutttonadsl.php',

        'data'      :  fd,

        'success' : function (response) {
            alert('Alterado com sucesso');
        },
        error: function () {
        alert('Erro');
        }
    });

});
```